# In what sense ${\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ a subgroup of SO(3,1), Spin(3,1), Spin$^c$(3,1), ℝ×SO(3,1), ℝ×Spin(3,1) or ℝ×Spin$^c$(3,1)?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, group-theory

For instance, it is well-known that $O(4)$ is in $GL(4,R)$.

In the same sense, is $GL^+(2,R)$ in either of 1 to 6:

1. ${\rm SO}(3,1)$,
2. ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$,
3. ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$,
4. $\mathbb{R}\times {\rm SO}(3,1)$,
5. $\mathbb{R}\times{\rm Spin}(3,1)$ or
6. $\mathbb{R}\times{\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$?

Is there a way to interpret, via isomorphisms, transformations in 1. to 6. as general linear transformations in 2D.

---

For example of what I have in mind:

Starting with 5., we have

$$
\mathbb{R}\times{\rm Spin}(3,1) \cong \mathbb{R} \times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong {\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C}).
$$

Finally,

$$
{\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong {\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R})\times {\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R}).
$$

In this case, $\mathbb{R}\times{\rm Spin}(3,1)$ can be interpreted as a double copy of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by representing $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathrm{R})$ "in" these groups? In standard terminology, representations are **on vector spaces**, not "in groups". 2. Likewise, what exactly is "are there any others in $\mathrm{GL}(4,\mathbb{R})$" supposed to mean? 3. What is the physics part of this question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Is there a subgroup of GL(4,R) with an isomorphism with GL(2,R). I am trying to figure out an experiment where one abuses the degrees of freedom of spacetime to cause a system to behave as if its has GL(2,R).

Comment: Of course there is, every $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(m)$ for $n<m$ via $A \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{1}_{m-n} & 0 \\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}$ where $\mathbf{1}_{m-n}$ is a $m-n$ identity matrix. I don't understand what this has to do with the lists of groups in the question or with "representations".

Comment: @ACuriousMind  Yes, I was aware of this result, but spacetime is one of the groups I listed 1 to 6 above. spacetime is not GL(4,R).

Comment: I don't know what "spacetime is one of the groups" means. Spacetime is a Lorentzian manifold, not a group. You need to use terminology correctly/provide a reference that uses terminology in the way you do here if you want other people to understand your question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The local group of spacetime is typically chosen from one of 1 to 6 depending on if its a classical (lorentz) or quantum theory (spin or spinc). Can we fit GL(2,R) in any of these groups via an isomorphism?

Comment: @ACuriousMind For example $\mathbb{R} \times {\rm Spin}(3,1) \cong \mathbb{R} \times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong {\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. I am close but I have ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ instead of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644368/11127

Comment: What is the physical motivation to consider $GL^+(2,R)$? Why not say $SL(2,R)$?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am trying to model 2D gravity using spinors (in the lab). I need GL+(2,R) because it is the structure group of the frame field on an orientable manifold.

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

1. It is trivial to fit $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})\cong SO^+(2,1)$ or $SL(2,\mathbb{R})\cong Spin^+(2,1)$ inside OP's mentioned 6 groups.
2. It is also trivial to fit $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}_+\times SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ inside OP's 3 last groups, at least OP's last 2 groups.
3. We may also be able to fit $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ inside OP's 3 first groups, but it is likely going to be unnatural from a physical perspective. The issue is that the dilation group $\mathbb{R}_+$ has an unbounded determinant/notion of volume, while we are trying to fit it inside groups with a bounded determinant/notion of volume.